# Why my code not working in return value for Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I wrote one program to find the matches. its working fine. If the string is not proper it has to return false. example if my string_ contains 2 commas or instead of reject or any if some other string came it has to return false. My string only expect string as reject or any

```
import re
string_ = '''192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5-192.168.1.7,reject,any,
reject,192.168.1.1/32,reject,any,
172.168.1.4-172.168.1.4,reject'''
result = re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/?\d{0,}|[any|reject]+', string_)
#print(result)
if result :
    print (True)
```

Expecting false for the string below

```
    test = '''192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5-192.168.1.7,reject,any,ip_address
reject,192.168.1.1/32,reject,any,
172.168.1.4-172.168.1.4,reject'''
bool(re.search('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/?\d{0,}|[any|reject]+', test))
```

Expected Out is False, My Out is True

```
test1 = '''192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5-192.168.1.7,reject,any,,,,
    reject,192.168.1.1/32,reject,any,
    172.168.1.4-172.168.1.4,reject'''
bool(re.search('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/?\d{0,}|[any|reject]+', test1))
```

Expected Out is False, My Out is True

Expected Out

`False`

Comment: Why do you even expect `False` in this? Your regex has many problems, you don't check for commas at all and your `[any|reject]+` will accept e.g. `aaa`...

Comment: why do you expect it to be false? you might want to debug or write your regex in an online parser to see what it does. here is your test data and regex as you can see there are many matches with your current regex https://regex101.com/r/GOHNWM/1

Comment: Please check [this solution](https://ideone.com/FTc6v4), is it what you need? Here is the resulting [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q4DMzS/1).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew its perfectly working, is there any way to pass this as one regex

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Q4DMzS/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?:/\d+)?(?:-\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?:/\d+)?)?|reject|any)(?:\s*,\s*(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?:/\d+)?(?:-\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?:/\d+)?)?|reject|any))*$
```

Since the regex is composed of blocks, it is easier to build it dynamically in the code:

```
import re
string_ = '''192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5-192.168.1.7,reject,any,ip_address
reject,192.168.1.1/32,reject,any,
172.168.1.4-172.168.1.4,reject'''
ip_rx = r'\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?:/\d+)?'
# More precise:
# ip_rx = r'(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}'
block=r"(?:{0}(?:-{0})?|reject|any)".format(ip_rx)
print(bool(re.search(r'^{0}(?:\s*,\s*{0})*$'.format(block), string_))) # => False
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6TA2qK)

**Details**

- `^{0}(?:\s*,\s*{0})*$` - matches a string that fully matches a `block` pattern that is followed with 0 or more occurrences of `,` and `block` pattern
- `(?:{0}(?:-{0})?|reject|any)` is the `block` pattern that matches either an `ip` pattern that can be optionally followed with `-` and an `ip` pattern or  `reject` or `any` substrings
- `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?:/\d+)?` is the `ip` pattern that can be improved to only match valid IPs, `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}`.